# Import users to Salesforce

Tags: data-loader

I am using the Data Loader to import a bunch of test users to Salesforce.

I have signed up for a Free Salesforce account and also created a Developer Sandbox.

When I try importing users, I get this error "License Limit Exceeded".

My Company profile shows I have 20 Salesforce platform user licenses available. I still get this error.

Can someone help please ?

Comment: Please check that you are using User License= Salesforce Platform in you CSV and not empty or Salesforce Platform

Answer (score 2):

Which Profile are you associating with these users? You'll need to assign them a profile that's compatible with Platform license.

Go to the screen where you add users manually (`https://instance.salesforce.com/005/e`) and check if LicenseType = 'Platform user' is available. If it's not - you'll have to start by making a Profile that uses this license type and then use that Profile's Id in your upload file.

Comment: Hey,

Thanks for the tip.

Yes I do see Salesforce Platform license type available. 

However, notice only 'Chatter Free' and 'Chatter Moderator' profiles are available.

Changed the Profile in the import file and it works now !

However, the newly added users are not visible under list of available users.

Not sure what 'Chatter Free' profile is used for.

Comment: Check http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_available.htm for example. Long story short - which objects (Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, custom objects...) will they be able to see. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8962/what-is-the-difference-between-the-salesforce-and-salesforce-platform-licens is a good one too. Chatter one is cheapest and most limited I think. Platform can give access to all custom objects.

Comment: If they're not visible in the list of all users - maybe you need to modify the list view to show all users? Can you navigate to one directly - search for that user in sidebar or the chatter's global search?