# Downgrading Salesforce license to salesforce platform license

Tags: reports-api, userlicense

What features do i loose downgrading Salesforce license to salesforce platform license.
one of my user is not able to access his own reports.
i gave him access to all system permissions for reports. still cant figure out the issue.

Comment: As far as I remember, you can't change license types on a user, so I presume you deactivated the old user and created a new user. If you did so, then all of their old configuration data would be lost, including all reports they previously had, email templates, etc. If not, you may want to clarify your question, otherwise it may be closed as being detailed enough.

Comment: when you edit the user, you can change User License which is inbetween Role and Profile. 

We have few profiles based on "Salesforce" User License and few profiles on "Salesforce Platform" User License.

I changed the User profile which is based on "Salesforce" User License to a different profile based on "Salesforce Platform" User License.

Comment: That's new'ish, I think. Ah well. If Run Reports is available on the new profile, the user should still have their reports *in their personal folder*. It's possible that they lost access to a report folder that they presumed was their personal folder but was actually a public reports folder.

Comment: I gave all permissions for reports in the new profile.
Still couldn't figure out the issue.

To test this i gave him a 3rd User profile which is based on "Salesforce" User License and everything works perfectly. 2nd profile and 3rd profile were exact copy of the 1st profile except the User License difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot downgrade. You will have to disable and reenable. Look at this question for differences:
[What is the difference between the "Salesforce" and "Salesforce Platform" licenses?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8962/what-is-the-difference-between-the-salesforce-and-salesforce-platform-licens/56732#56732)