# Error Message- Standard tabsets are not permitted for this profile

Tags: custom-object, permissions, console, custom-profile

I was able to resolve the below issue by googling it but couldn't able to understand whats wrong and how suggested method resolved the issue. Can someone please help me to get a better understanding on this.

**Background:**
I was trying to create a Custom object and assigned to an App. It was working fine and able to see from Admin profile. Then I tried to login as a Standard platform user and view the same App to see my Custom object. But couldn't able to see from a Standard platform user as this profile didn't have any object permission on new Custom Object.

**Issue:**
I was trying to assign the Object permissions to my Custom Object under a Custom Profile cloned from "Standard Platform user". I was using my Admin profile to do this.

But I am getting below error
"Standard tabsets are not permitted for this profile 00e28000001RvKL"
*--Where 00e28000001RvKL is my Custom Profile "Std_Platform_User" cloned from Standard profile "Standard Platform user.*

**Google & Resolution Step:**

1) https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000186561&language=en_US

2) https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Disable-Custom-App-at-the-Profile-level&language=en_US

I followed the Step 2 to disable the checkbox from visible for "Service Cloud Console app" assigned to  Custom Profile "Std_Platform_User". Then tried to assign the Object permissions to my Custom Object for Custom Profile "Std_Platform_User" and it worked. Also able to see the new Custom Object under particular Apps for Custom Profile "Std_Platform_User".

**My Question**
Whats the significance of visibility setting of "Service Cloud Console app" with related to object permission setting to a Custom profile for an App. Is this something related to License between Console & profile or something else?

*Please help me to get understand this as I am new to Saleforce and dose'n have any hands own experience and trying for Admin Certification by myself.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My understanding is that a Salesforce Platform license does not allow access to tabsets aka standard apps. The service cloud console an example of an app, so by having that new profile enabled in a console app it is trying to give it access a standard tabset. This causes a validation error when you try to save the profile. It's not strictly related to custom object permissions, merely that you tried to save a profile which caused the validations to run. Removing the profile from the console clears this invalid condition and lets you make the rest of the changes successfully.

See also [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8962/what-is-the-difference-between-the-salesforce-and-salesforce-platform-licens) that has a bit more detail about the licenses.